# Recursion return 1 statement

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
     int num;
     ofstream file("text.txt", ios::binary);
     for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
         cout<<"Enter an integer";
         cin>>num;
         file.write((char*)num, sizeof(num));
     }
     out.close();
    system("pause");
}
```

I am getting the following message "Unhandled exception at 0x000000000: The operation completed successfully".

Comment: I see no recursion there, nor any `return` statement. Nor any code that will actually compile, since `out` is not defined anywhere. We only help with real problems, not made-up ones :-)

Comment: Don't use C-style casts, and you'll immediately realize your problem. Just be nice to yourself!

Answer (score 2):

In this statement, you get number, use it as address in *memory*, which is most likely invalid.

```
file.write((char*)num, sizeof(num));
```

If you want to write `num` in binary representation, you should get its address first:

```
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&num), sizeof(num));
```

Note the ampersand which is unary operator for getting addresses. I have also used `reinterpret_cast` which is C++ type conversion for such cases. C-style conversion may hide errors (but `reinterpret_cast` is also valid for `int`->`*` conversion).

P.S. `void main()` is an invalid prototype of main. It should return `int` at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
cin>>num;
file.write((char*)num, sizeof(num));
```

If you didn't input a number that represents the address of a valid, allocated memory at least the size of an `int` (and it's quite likely that you didn't), then the above will have undefined behaviour and is likely the cause for your crash.

Comment: It took a while to understand your contention but I think I finally got it. However, the number you enter doesn't have to be the address of a null terminated string, it just has to point to a block of bytes big enough to hold an `int`. `ofstream.write` doesn't care about C-style strings.

Comment: @paxdiablo oh yea, thanks. There's the streamsize parameter and indeed, no null termination. I've fixed my answer.